# xampp not sending the mails

Tags: php, email, xampp

I have installed xampp along with FakeMail and Mercury , tried with them didn't work then I installed anther STMP server QK STMP Server , also it didn't work , in side the php am sending the mail as following `mail($email, $subject, $message, "From: $adminemail \nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion());` , it seems like it does not bind the mail to the stamp server , because I can't see that in the logs...

php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = localhost
 smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

what is wrong here!?

Comment: I'm confused--do you want Apache to run a mail server, or are you running an external SMTP server at localhost:25 that you want Apache to use?

Comment: I have tried both , and both not working!